# Hosting a WCF service in asp.net mvc 1 aplication and enabling metadata exchange

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, hosting, localhost

I want to host a wcf service inside an asp.net MVC (1.0) application, I created a .svc file as it has to be done for web applications, but nothing works. When I try to reach the metadata endpoint the request fails because the request is passing through the rouitng system, so if I have an .svc published in `http:localhost/myapp/services/service1.svc` and I try to reach it's mex endpoint the request fails because no `servicesController` if found.

I have to create a route record to correctly host and publish my service?

I have to specify a particular configuration for wcf services inside a mvc project to avoid routing to be applied?

All the answers about the topic I saw tends to sais just *..no, you have not..* or *..hosting is inside IIS..* but wothout providing detailed explaination.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I might be overlooking something obvious, but the solution which comes to mind would be to ignore all requests to .svc resources by adding an Ignore rule in your route collection:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("*.svc");
```

Comment: this is not so obvious.. because doing so the handler used to serve the request is the staticcontenthandler and this will produce a 404.3 error